# Modify WordPress search behaviour in backend?

Tags: filters, search

Is it somehow possible in WordPress to modify the default search in backend? At the moment I can only search when I start with the beginning of the search term. But I want to search with the second part of the string too.

I tried "*3985" but nothing is working :-/... WOuld be great if someone could help me.

Big thanks in advance.

[image: image for explanation]

Comment: What are query strings in the URL after you press "Search" button?

Comment: Thank you for your time: "/wp-admin/edit.php?s=CZYXTLTS&post_status=all&post_type=wc_voucher&action=-1&m=0&lang=de&paged=1&action2=-1"

Comment: I can reproduce the problem only using asterisk "*3985" in the search string. Without it ("3985") everything works fine. The URL looks legit.

Comment: Ah Sorry. The first string I posted is working but this string (3985) gives no results:  "/wp-admin/edit.php?s=3985&post_status=all&post_type=wc_voucher&action=-1&m=0&lang=de&paged=1&action2=-1" So only the first part is searchable?

Comment: Both "CZYXTLTS" and "3985" with no asterisk (*) works fine for me. Do you use WordPress.com Store?

Comment: ? That's the backend interface of WC Product voucher plugin. I thought it is a general problem with the WordPRess Backend search functionality?